# Solving Conditional Probability Unknkowns

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

Given:

A is the number of people who have a disease is 0.01

B is when a drug tests positive

$\mathsf P(B\mid A)=0.9$

$\mathsf P(B\mid A')= 0.05$

I solved for $\mathsf P(B)=0.0585$ and $\mathsf P(A \cap B) = 0.009$

The question asks what is the probability of a person having the disease given that two independent tests that were done on him turned up positive?

Essentially the questions asks for $\mathsf P(A\mid C)$, where $C$ is both tests turning up positive or $B^2$.

I found $\mathsf P(C)$ from multiplying $0.0585$ by itself, but how do I find the probability that: A occurs and B occurs on both tests?

I'm leaning towards $\mathsf P(A \cap B) \times \mathsf P(A \cap B)$ since both tests are independent. However, when I divide by $\mathsf P(C)$ I got $0.02367$ which is smaller than $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$.

Shouldn't two positive independent tests increase the probability that the person indeed has the disease? I think my difficulty is in the syllogism of defining what A occurring and B occurring on both tests is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the person has the disease, the probability of $2$ positives is $(0.9)^2$.

Given the person does not have the disease, the probability of $2$ consecutive positives is $(0.05)^2$.

Thus the probability of what you call $C$ is $(0.1)(0.9)^2+(0.99)(0.05)^2$.

The required conditional probability is therefore 
$$\frac{(0.1)(0.9)^2}{(0.1)(0.9)^2+(0.99)(0.05)^2}.$$

**Remark:** When you do the calculation, you will find that the answer accords better with the intuition. Yes, two tests are (a lot) better than one. The assumption of independence is, however, not entirely reasonable.

The answer has been brief. If detail is needed, please leave a comment.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your reasoning for multiplying the complement of each of the positive test probability? how exactly did you get C? Why isnt it P(B)^2?

Comment: $(\Pr(B))^2$ is the answer to the following question. We pick a person at random, test her. Then we take a person at random, test him. What is the probability they both test positive? I did not multiply complements, I calculated probabilities. The probability a sick person tests positive twice in a row is, by independence, $(0.9)(0.9)$. A similar calculation gives $(0.05)(0.05)$ for the probability a healthy person tests positive twice in a row. Then the probability of $C$ is calculated using the same reasoning as the reasoning you used to calculate $\Pr(B)$.

Comment: @Anson When testing *the same person*, the tests are only **conditionally independent** on having the disease (or not).  There results are not *unconditionally* independent.  So you must use the law of total probability first.  $\begin{align}\mathsf P(B_1\cap B_2) & = \mathsf P(B_1\cap B_2\mid A)\mathsf P(A) + \mathsf P(B_1\cap B_2\mid A')\mathsf P(A') \\ & = \mathsf P(B_1\mid A)\mathsf P(B_2\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B_1\mid A')\mathsf P(B_2\mid A')\mathsf P(A')\end{align}$

Comment: Ahh, I see. I did not take into consideration a healthy person testing positive for both tests. Could you confirm whether my calculations for **P(B)** are correct though?

Comment: @Anson Yeap. It's fine.  $\mathsf P(B)=\mathsf P(B\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\mid A')\mathsf P(A') = 0.0585$

Comment: I checked your answer for $\Pr(B)$. It is correct. You did not show how you did it, but it is very improbable in this case that you would get the right number with the wrong method.